# How to use Vue-i18n after Change Migrations

Tags: internationalization, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using the [electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue) boilerplate,

i have tried to add [Vue-i18n](https://github.com/MattyRad/vue-i18n) to it , but after the owner of vue-i18n

change the Migrations:
http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/en/migrations.html

**i get confuesd How to add i18n** , and Langue files must be in seperate folder like:

--locales:

----en.json /or/.js

**and How to add Strings in Tag Like this to be Translated ?**

```
<menu-item to="/landingPage" title="My Profile" />
```

must be like this!!

```
<menu-item to="/landingPage" title="{{ $t('My Profile') }}" />
```

but this won't Work for me ??

"vue-i18n": "^6.1.1"

Comment: What version of vue did you use?

Comment: the version is :Vue 2.2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with i18n but you cannot use mustache-like sintax inside tags' attribute, you should bind the attribute for that to work. test:

```
<menu-item to="/landingPage" v-bind:title="$t('My Profile')" />
```

or the shortcut:

```
<menu-item to="/landingPage" :title="$t('My Profile')" />
```

Of course, this assuming that

```
<p>{{ $t('My Profile') }}</p>
```

is working properly)